# Media query for devices supporting hover

Tags: css, hover, media-queries, touch, interaction-media-features

I'd like to provide separate behaviour for browsers supporting hover (e.g. desktop browsers) and ones which don't (e.g. touchscreen devices). Specifically I want to declare a hover state on browsers that support it, but not for browsers that don't, so as to avoid having mobile browsers emulate it with extra taps, as this breaks other interactions on the page - by not defining a hover state for those browsers this is avoided.

I've read up on the [Interaction Media Queries](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-4/#hover) feature and it looks like it should do the trick. I'd be able to do something like:

```
@media (hover: none) {
  /* behaviour for touch browsers */
}
```

According to [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-media-interaction) it is available on all the browsers I need to support except IE11 and Firefox.

So I wondered if I could do it the other way around - since the main touch devices all support it, then negate it:

```
@media not (hover: none) {
  /* behaviour for desktop browsers */
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work at all.

Pseudocode example of what I'm trying to do:

```
.myelement {
  /* some styling */
  /* note: no hover state here */
}
@media(this device supports hover) {
  .myelement:hover {
    /* more styling */
  }
}
```

So, is there a way to make this work in the way intended, or am I down the wrong track?

Comment: Please **don't** use the media query "hover".

I'm working with a mouse on my 27" monitor, but all of my browsers have the setting "hover:none" although I like and am able to hover a lot.

Maybe all my browser have hover:none because my laptop where my peripheral devices are connected to has a touch screen.

Maybe you can try the any-hover media query https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/any-hover

Comment: @Andreas Make this one an answer so it is prominent enough to be found. I was going crazy because of this. Everyone is talking about hover and neither of my browsers was capable of either detecting my mouse via `pointer:fine` nor accepting hover via `hover:hover`. But this hint was solving it ...

Comment: I've made a website where you can test the setting of your browser referring to this problem
https://andreasburg.de/lenovo-browser-hover-check.html

Comment: now in at least 2021, you have two keywords for `hover` as mentioned in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/hover) in MDN docs,  not sure you were looking for this implementation, but hope someone would find this useful in the future!

Comment: @Andreas could you add tests for the media query "pointer" to your test website? It would be convenient to have tests for the 2 related queries in 1 place.

Comment: Note that Samsung devices have a bug where they report `(hover:hover)` instead of `(hover:none)`! https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/css-media-hover-samsung.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to Dekel's comments I solved this by running the logic in JS and applying a class instead:

e.g.

```
const canHover = !(matchMedia('(hover: none)').matches);
if(canHover) {
  document.body.classList.add('can-hover');
}
```

Then in the stylesheet:

```
.myElement {
  background: blue;
}
.can-hover .myElement:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

I've tested this on desktop Chrome, Safari and Firefox, and iOS Safari and it works as expected.

Comment: as said, js can (almost) always help you there :) +1 from me on the solution

Answer (score 74):

`not` should prefix media type (screen, print, all, etc) and not media feature (hover, point, etc).

Wrong:

```
@media not (hover: none)
```

Correct:

```
@media not all and (hover: none)
```

Yes, its unintuitive and weird. [Source (see comments)](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2012/11/what_the_hells.html).

So you do not need javascript to alternate result of media query.

Comment: Upvote. Unlike the above, this works without any javascript. It is indeed counterintuitive.

Comment: Great trick! Just note that IE11 appears to ignore this rule altogether. Using another IE-specific hack, it appears the following works (in spite of it being the negated version of the workaround):

`@media not all and (hover: none), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {`

Comment: Neither `@media (hover: none)` nor the negation `@media not all and (hover: none)` do anything in Firefox. That browser doesn't support hover https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1035774  but should there not be a way of writing the `not` such that if the subject of `not` is undefined/unrecognized then it evaluates to false (and the entire media query evaluates to true)?

Comment: @EoghanM did you ever figure that out? I was wondering the same thing.

Comment: `not (hover: none)` is not, or at least no longer, wrong. It's correct, according to Media Queries 4. It just isn't supported by any browser yet, frustratingly. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455958/why-does-not-some-width-xem-media-query-never-fire/24456052#24456052

Comment: @EoghanM: That's one of the frustrating limitations of `@media` rules. The only workaround is through [using the cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44244221/is-it-possible-to-do-a-css-supports-check-on-a-media-rule/44248682#44248682).

Comment: @Jake Wilson: See above.

Comment: @JakeWilson I've fleshed out what I finally went with (in terms of negation) in a full answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54147825/6691
TLDR: didn't find a way of writing the negation in FF yet.

Comment: Stupid question, why not using `@media (hover) {...desktop styles...}` ?

Comment: Actually I don't get why all are trying to negate the condition which can be achieved straight forward by the keyword `hover` instead of `none`. Maybe it's implemented now but not in the time the question was asked, refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/hover) for more info!

Answer (score 20):

From the specs:

> `none`
>
> > Indicates that the primary pointing system can’t hover, or there is no pointing system. Examples include touchscreens and screens that use a drawing stylus.
> >     Pointing systems that can hover, but for which doing so is inconvenient and not part of the normal way they are used, also match this value.
> >
> > **For example, a touchscreen where a long press is treated as hovering would match hover: none.**

If your browser (mobile/touch) support long-press to simulate hover, the usage of `hover: none` will not work. What you can do is just use a default value and override it (with default css precedence):

```
body {
    background: red;
}

@media (hover: hover) {
  body {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

Desktop will have `blue` background and mobile/touch will have `red` background

Check the following example:
https://jsfiddle.net/mcy60pvt/1/

To check the long-press option of the mobile you can use this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/mcy60pvt/3/

In the above example the green block has `:hover` definition for both desktop and mobile, however for desktop the background will change to `yellow` and for mobile (with long-press) it will change to `white`.

Here is the css for the last example:

```
body {
    background: red;
}
div.do-hover {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: green;
}
div.do-hover:hover {
  background: white;
}

@media (hover: hover) {
  body {
    background: blue;
  }
  div.do-hover:hover {
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```

In this example - browsers that don't support `:hover` will view the *hover me* box with green background, and while "hover" (touch/long-press) - the background will change to white.

### update

As for the added pseudo code:

```
.myelement {
    /* some styling #1 */
    /* note: no hover state here */
}
@media(hover: hover) {
    .myelement {
        /* some styling that override #1 styling in case this browser suppot the hover*/
    }
    .myelement:hover {
        /* what to do when hover */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this leaves me in the same situation where browsers not supporting the hover media query don't behave correctly.

Comment: why not? If they don't support the hove media they will get the background `green` (unless you add a new background color inside the `hover: hover` part).

Comment: I'll add it to the answer, 1 minute

Comment: I've added an example to the question to try to clarify. The idea would be that a hover state is only declared for browsers which support hover, so that mobile browsers don't try to emulate it.

Comment: It's the same issue, I'm afraid - Firefox users won't get the hover as in that browser the hover media query will return false. This is why I was trying to do it backwards (i.e. "if not unsupported")

Comment: Firefox desktop/mobile/other device?

Comment: All of them - Mozilla haven't implemented it yet. It'll be the same for IE.

Comment: Ok, so this is a bit of a different question. It's like to ask "how can I use css4 tricks with browsers that only support css3?" :) well, mostly you can't. If Firefox ignores the `hover:hover` definition - you don't really have something you can do with it (in pure css). You can use javascript to add class to the `body` element and use css based on that class (is-firefox, is-support-hover, is-mobile, etc...)

Comment: You're probably right - I was hoping to avoid having to do that but it might end up having to be done via script. Was hoping to just be able to treat a lack of support as a "false", but looks like that might not be possible.

Comment: You can always use the media query with specific width/height of mobiles, it should be pretty good...

Comment: The hover media queries apparently do not work for some samsung devices. On a galaxy s10, it incorrectly shows the blue background in the first jsfiddle. :(

Comment: I have noticed that the media query `@media(hover: hover)` does not work on Chrome, however it does on other browsers.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this Sass mixin to style the hover, it will use the recommended substitute `:active` for touch devices. Works on all modern browsers and IE11.

```
/**
 Hover styling for all devices and browsers
 */
@mixin hover() {
    @media (hover: none) {
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        &:active {
            @content;
        }
    }

    @media (hover: hover), all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
        &:hover {
            @content;
        }
    }
}

.element {
    @include hover {
         background: red;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution I found, but FYI, it doesn't support Firefox 63 and below.

Comment: @Pluto Thanks for the insight. That's not too bad, those versions fall below a global usage of 0.1%.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Artin´s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42363147/4316314) we can address only devices that support hover with pure css, with `@media not all and (hover: none)`. It looks weird but it works.

I made a Sass mixin out of this for easier use:

```
@mixin hover-supported {
    @media not all and (hover: none) {
        &:hover {
            @content;
        }
    }
}
```

The following would change background-color of `.container` from red to blue on hover for devices that support hover, no change for touch devices:

```
.container {
    background-color: red;

    @include hover-supported() {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To support Firefox (see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1035774 ), you need to potentially write some rules twice. Note, although not specified in the question I've added `pointer: coarse` on the assumption that the purpose of these rules is to target mobile screens:

```
/* BEGIN devices that DON'T pinch/zoom */
/* If https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1035774 
is fixed then we can wrap this section in a ...
@media not all and (pointer: coarse) and (hover: none) {
.. and do away with the 'NEGATE' items below */

.myelement {
  /* some styling that you want to be desktop only (style as an anchor on desktop) */
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  border: none;
}
/* END devices that DON'T pinch/zoom */

/* BEGIN devices that DO pinch/zoom */   
@media (pointer: coarse) and (hover: none) {
  .myelement {
    /* style as a large button on mobile */
    font-size: inherit;  /* maintain e.g. larger mobile font size */
    text-decoration: none;  /* NEGATE */
    border: 1px solid grey;
  }

  .myelement:hover {
    /* hover-only styling */
  }
}
/* END devices that DO pinch/zoom */
```

The combination of `(pointer: coarse) and (hover: none)` should become more useful to target mobile devices as mobile screens become larger and we lose the correlation between pixel dimensions and mobile vs. desktop (already the case when you wish to distinguish between tablet and desktop)

Comment: This bug has been fixed a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use the media query "hover". I'm working with a mouse on my 27" monitor, but all of my browsers have the setting "hover:none" although I like and am able to hover a lot. Maybe all my browser have hover:none because my laptop where my peripheral devices are connected to has a touch screen. Maybe you can try the any-hover media query developer [mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/any-hover](https://mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/any-hover)

I've made a website where you can test the setting of your browser referring to this problem [andreasburg.de/browser-hover-check.html](https://andreasburg.de/browser-hover-check.html)