# Why are hover styles applied on tap on mobile devices?

Tags: html, css

My button changes its color on :hover, see:

```
button {
  background-color: orange;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: darkorange;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/oepb5ks4/

Works great on desktop, but on mobile - where :hover should not exist – the browser* still changes the color, but *after* touching the button.

1. Why is that behavior? Am I missing something? What makes somebody think that implementing (parts of) :hover on mobile browsers makes *any* sense?
2. Is there a nice and clean solution for this (preferably without Media Queries or JavaScript)?

*Tested in Chrome (in "Device Mode") as well as in iOS Safari.

Comment: this known hover is activated by a click. Imagine you create a menu with subitems that you show on hover, on mobile it will be click

Comment: On mobile, when you click, hover is activated, and If you "pass finger" over the button or something else that have state hover, the hover also activated, so hover exists on mobile too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you CSS you could filter for mobile devices with the `@media` rules and filters ([documentation at w3](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)). You could state "if the media has the hover functionality then the hover color should be orange":

```
@media not all and (hover: none) {
    a:hover{
        color: orange
    }
}
```

You also could try to [detect it with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser) and manually adjust the color to always be orange when on mobile.

I believe that your problem occurs because in order to click on a button on PC you must have hovered over it before, so the color changes on mobile after you clicked it.

**Update** I just read the comment under the question by Temani Afif: apparently `:hover`s are "converted" to something like `:onclick` on mobile because of the lack of the hover feature on phones. As many websites have on hover menus mobile users couldn't access those if they wouldn't translate it.

Another thing you could try is to force the color of the visited links with this:

```
a:visited { 
  color: orange!important;
}
```

**Update 2** Included the new media tag and took advice from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42363147/7454177) on a different question and it's comment on how to use not and the @media rules.

Comment: Probably even better than using the screen width is to check for hover existence: `@media (hover: none) { ... }`

Comment: @kraftwer1 Can you confirm that this works? If so, I will include it in my answer.

Comment: it seems to work everywhere except IE11 :-)
https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-media-interaction