# Difference between media any-hover and hover

Tags: css, media-queries

The documentation is identical for both entries.

I use `@media (hover: hover) {...}` to run a style only on desktop to hover, apparently some smartphones will run it by mistake too, would replacing with `any-hover` fix the problem. If yes, why ? Otherwise commits to distinguish mobile / desktop as behavior (notably function on hover).

After two days on google or here i can't find a difference, maybe a user's primary input mechanism story, but it's not very clear ...

Thanks

Comment: as per MDN hover tests only 'primary input mechanism' and any-hover test for 'any available input mechanisms'.  If you have not read this https://stackoverflow.com/q/40532204/15273968  or https://andreasburg.de/browser-hover-check.html

Comment: Thank ! yes I saw this little subtlety. But without understanding fundamentally the differences and consequences.